# Blender force field wind noise is lame?

Tags: python, animation, force-fields

Wind force field noise goes to 10. Noise is lame. Does little because equilibrium is quickly reached. My sample cloth banner should be in chaotic motion.

Try animating the strength as handmade noise. Can't do this from python?

Scripting workspace logs wind force field strength modification for python edit:

```
bpy.context.object.field.strength = 150
```

Same workspace does not log keyframes entered for this field. Neither the object nor it's `field` field has a `keyframe_insert` method. I normally animate a `location`, `rotation`, or a `value` datapath within that `keyframe_insert` method?

Comment: maybe provide your blend file and link/add an animation how it should look like? for sure the force fields (did u try turbulence?) are strong and capable enough to produce chaotic motion.  I doubt that making a handmade noise is necessary...